# How can I pass build arguments in Android externalNativeBuild CMake options?

Tags: android, cmake

I don't know how to pass the `-j` option to the native build system through `externalNativeBuild` CMake options.

I've read [the official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.1/com/android/build/api/dsl/ExternalNativeCmakeOptions). The arguments field is used to pass arguments at configuration time.

What I need is to pass arguments to native build system at build time.

For example, pass '-j' option to ninja or Unix Makefile.
`cmake --build . -- -j`.

```
Usage: cmake --build <dir>             [options] [-- [native-options]]
       cmake --build --preset <preset> [options] [-- [native-options]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at [the CMake docs for `-j`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-build-j), it falls back to an environment variable, [`CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/envvar/CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL.html) if you don't pass `-j`. Set that environment variable in the environment of the Gradle process, and I think that unless Gradle does anything to prevent this from happening, the environment variable should be "passed down to" / "inherited by" the child build process (assuming it runs the build process as a child process).